# Unable to match IP regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Following is my code I am trying to validate IP addresses in front end, but somehow this Regex is not working -

```
var patt = /[0-255]\.[0-255]\.[0-255]\.[0-255]/;
var str = "90.89.99.90";

if(str.match(patt))
  console.log("Valid IP");
else
  console.log("Invalid IP");
```

It should output - **Valid IP**

while these kind of IPs should return - **Invalid IP**

> "fd.45.67.90", "256.67.67.89", "@@.45.67.90" etc

Let me know what I am doing wrong with regex.

Comment: You should use str.test(patt) instead of str.match, because .match returns an array of matches instead of true / false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex ranges don't do what you think they do. A `[x-y]` range contains all characters in ascii from `x` to `y`.

Therefore `[0-255]` matches characters from `0` to `2` (aka `0`, `1` and `2`) and `5` or in short - `[0125]`.

---

To match a number from `0` to `255`, you could do:

```
\d\d?|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])
```

The idea:

- `\d\d?` - one or two digit numbers
- `1\d\d` - numbers from `100` to `199`
- `2[0-4]\d` - numbers from `200` to `249`.
- `25[0-5]` - numbers from `250` to `255`

---

To match an entire IP, you could do:

```
^((\d\d?|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(\d\d?|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$
```

Comment: I tried your regex but its not working ... is it something else I need to add here ?

Comment: @TechSolvr, the regex will match a single number 0 - 255, not an ip. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It should not validate this

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks a lot !! ..you can add this ans I will upvote your answer too :)

Comment: I posted my variant of the IP matching regex based on this answer.

Answer (score 3):

`[...]` denotes a "character class" meaning that it lists characters that should match there; it matches any single character from what you list. So your regex is checking each segment for a **single character** which is any of 0, 1, 2, or 5 (`0-2` gives us 0, 1, and 2; then 5 gives us 5, and the second 5 is ignored). It should be checking for digits (`\d`), and 1-3 of them (`{1,3}`):

```
var patt = /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/;
```

You might also want `^` (start of input) and `$` (end of input), so that `foo123.123.123.123bar` doesn't match:

```
var patt = /^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/$;
```

This is, of course, not sufficient to check that the IP is **valid**. It just checks that there are numbers where expected; it would happily call `891.262.999.42` valid.

If you want to properly validate it (e.g., that the numbers are in the valid ranges, filtering out invalid combinations of segments, etc), you could extract the IP part of [this comprehensive URL validation regex](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294) (since URLs can contain IP addresses, it covers that). Thankfully, Diego and the other authors have nicely commented it, clearly identifying which bits do what:

```
//
// Regular Expression for URL validation
//
// Author: Diego Perini
// Updated: 2010/12/05
// License: MIT
//
// Copyright (c) 2010-2013 Diego Perini (http://www.iport.it)
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
// obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
// files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
// restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
// copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
// Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
// conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
// included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
// EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
// OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
// NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
// HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
// WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
// FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
// OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//
// the regular expression composed & commented
// could be easily tweaked for RFC compliance,
// it was expressly modified to fit & satisfy
// these test for an URL shortener:
//
//   http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex
//
// Notes on possible differences from a standard/generic validation:
//
// - utf-8 char class take in consideration the full Unicode range
// - TLDs have been made mandatory so single names like "localhost" fails
// - protocols have been restricted to ftp, http and https only as requested
//
// Changes:
//
// - IP address dotted notation validation, range: 1.0.0.0 - 223.255.255.255
//   first and last IP address of each class is considered invalid
//   (since they are broadcast/network addresses)
//
// - Added exclusion of private, reserved and/or local networks ranges
//
// - Made starting path slash optional (http://example.com?foo=bar)
//
// - Allow a dot (.) at the end of hostnames (http://example.com.)
//
// Compressed one-line versions:
//
// Javascript version
//
// /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$/i
//
// PHP version
//
// _^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]-*)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]-*)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$_iuS
//
var re_weburl = new RegExp(
  "^" +
    // protocol identifier
    "(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)" +
    // user:pass authentication
    "(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?" +
    "(?:" +
      // IP address exclusion
      // private & local networks
      "(?!(?:10|127)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})" +
      "(?!(?:169\\.254|192\\.168)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})" +
      "(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})" +
      // IP address dotted notation octets
      // excludes loopback network 0.0.0.0
      // excludes reserved space >= 224.0.0.0
      // excludes network & broacast addresses
      // (first & last IP address of each class)
      "(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])" +
      "(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}" +
      "(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))" +
    "|" +
      // host name
      "(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)" +
      // domain name
      "(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*" +
      // TLD identifier
      "(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,}))" +
      // TLD may end with dot
      "\\.?" +
    ")" +
    // port number
    "(?::\\d{2,5})?" +
    // resource path
    "(?:[/?#]\\S*)?" +
  "$", "i"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex variation (based on [ndn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2423164/ndn)'s [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34579651/3832970)) that will check if *the entire input text* is a valid IP:

```
^(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ6lA8/1)

Here is a solution that can be used to *extract* valid IPs from larger text:

```
\b(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\b
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ6lA8/2)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of string (replace with `\b` word boundary if you need not match at the beginning of string only)
- `(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}` - 3 occurrences of

  - `(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))` - 1- or 2-digit sequence, or a `1xx` number (`1\d{2}`) or a range of integer numbers in-between 200-255 range (thanks to `2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5])`)
  - `\.` - a literal period
- `(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))` - see above (just the last part of the IP address)
- `$` - end of string (replace with `\b` if you just need a whole word match).

*NOTE*: In JS, you can use the literal notation to declare these regexps, e.g.:

```
/\b(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\b/g
/^(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$/
```