# Regex for find All ip address except IP address starts with 172

Tags: javascript, php, regex, node.js, regex-negation

I want regex to find IP address which not starts with 172.0.0.0.

I have written some regex `^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$` which finds all ip address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to match IP regex in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579640/unable-to-match-ip-regex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` in a regex is character that matches everything. To use it in this context, you must escape it.

Also to limit it to just ip addresses that start with 172, simply hardcode it into your regex like so:

```
^172\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/A-1wHazIwAAdd7r1)

You could then use this to filter out any matches already made.

---

Alternatively, if you're not starting with a list of ip addresses, you could use a negative look-ahead to grab them all straight away.

```
^(?!172)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CLPck7hmtVqTWosY)

---

Be a little careful in that this may match more than ip addresses - for example `400.660.226.602` would be captured - even though real IP4 addresses do not contain numbers higher than `255`. Perhaps this won't affect your use case - but it's something to remember.

---

As per the comments below, if you are searching for IP addresses anywhere in the document, rather than on their own line, use `\b` instead of `^` and `$`

```
\b(?!172)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/F8jTfUWwUuj3X2M9)

This would match log formats for example, which contain an ip address within the message rather than on it's own line.

> [10:01:22] Connection from `10.14.242.211` established.

Comment: +1 for the very good explanation - be careful though with addresses in the wild, I'd suggest a word boundary in this case.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by a word boundary? In the regex in the question, and the suggested ones in my answer ``^`` and ``$`` are used...

Comment: Right. So you would use the boundary to ensure that the 172 address (which is being partially captured) would not be captured as a 72 one? This wouldn't have happened if you used both the ``^`` and ``$`` characters as per the actual example - but depending on what is actually being parsed it's a very good point.

Comment: See my answer using `\b` which works in both positions (even at the start/end).

Comment: Thankyou so much shadow and great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead if you're looking for addresses in the wild:

```
\b((?!172)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b
```

See a [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yP9rW2/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^172\.(?:\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b|null)$
```

It not only check ip address start with 172 but it also check for valid ip - address i.e each value can not be more than 255

Live demo is here https://regex101.com/r/lA1gA4/1